# how to display object details in alert in ionic 1

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, alert

On clicking a button i am invoking this funtion

```
$scope.showAlert = function(item) {
   var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
     title: 'Data',
     template: JSON.stringify(item),
   });

   alertPopup.then(function(res) {
     console.log('Thank you for not eating my delicious ice cream cone');
   });
 };
```

my object look like this

```
{id: 2, firstname: "abcd", lastname: "xyza", class: "1", attendance: "123"}
```

i am able to get the alert in object formate but i want to dis play in this way .

```
var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
         title: 'Data',
         template: 'firstname: item.firstname,
                   lastname: item.lastname,
                   class: item.class,
                   attendance: item.attendance'
       });
```

it will be print in one line after another line how can i achive this in ionic 1

Comment: the same way you output angular variables in HTML everywhere else, use `{{ }}`.  e.g. `{{item.firstname}}`.

Comment: i tried like this `template: 'firstname:{{item.firstname}} ',` but i am getting nothing in after firstname @Claies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will help you

```
var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
         title: 'Data',
         template: "firstname: "+item.firstname+' ,'+"<br>"+"lastname:                         "+item.lastname+' ,'+"<br>"+"class: "+item.class+' ,'+"<br>"+"attendance: "+item.attendance
       });
```